# JSON file only loads in the fuction but once finished the loaded data is gone in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am trying to parse through JSON file grabbing all its data and put it into a variable so I can use it in other components. The code I grabbed works fine for parsing through json file. On **line 22**, `console.log(data)` prints out all the objects in json without an issue, however on **line 27**, `console.log(data)` prints out undefined. Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

```
var jsonData = require('../../../../file.json');

    var data; 

    function loadJSON(jsonfile, callback) {   

        var jsonObj = new XMLHttpRequest();
        jsonObj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
        jsonObj.open('GET', "../../file.json", true); //asynchronous because true
        jsonObj.onreadystatechange = function () {
              if (jsonObj.readyState == 4 && jsonObj.status == "200") {
                callback(jsonObj.responseText);
              }
        };
        jsonObj.send(null);  
     }

    function load() {
        loadJSON(jsonData, function(response) {
            data = JSON.parse(response);
    //line 21      
            console.log(data);
        });
    }

    load();

    //line 27
    console.log(data);

    const JSONLoad = data;

    module.exports = JSONLoad;
```

Answer (score 1):

The AJAX call is asynchronous so `console.log(data)` will be called immediately after `load()`, before the request receives data.